# Spy on an attribute/function of a private variable with Jasmine

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, private

I have a function with variable functionality based on file it reads, which is controlled via a `Map` it keeps in memory:

> `file1.ts`

```
function f1(x: number): number {
  // do far-reaching things
  return 1;
}

function f2(x: number): number {
  // do different far-reaching things
  return 2;
}

function f3(x: number): number {
  // do still-different far-reaching things
  return 3;
}

const myMap: Map<string, (number) => number> = new Map<string, () => void>([
  ['key1', f1],
  ['key2', f2],
  ['key3', f3],
]

export function doThing(filename: string): number {
  // open file, make some database calls, and figure out the name of a key
  // ...
  let fileToExecute = myMap.get(key);
  return fileToExecute(someValueDerivedFromFile);
}
```

`f1`, `f2`, and `f3` all do much more than shown here, and each requires a lot of mocks to be tested successfully.

As the code grows more developed and use cases continue, there will be an arbitrary number of functions that might need to be called, based on an expanding set of inputs. `doThing()` is complicated and takes its information from a lot of different sources, including both the contents of given file and a database, which helps it choose which file to execute. From a client's point of view, `doThing()` is the only function it cares about. Thus, it's the only one `export`ed by this file.

I'm trying to test the mechanism in `doThing()` that figures out what `key` it should use. I don't want to mock `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` specifically - I want to present many more options, pointed to by other things I'm mocking for `doThing()`. However, to check if it's calling the *correct* fake method, I need to figure out which fake method it's calling. My attempted solution uses typecasting to try to pull the private `myMap` out of the file and then spy on its `get()` method:

> `file1.spec.ts`

```
import * as file1 from '../src/file1'
...
it("calls the correct fake method", () => {
  // lots of other mocks
  let spies = [
    jasmine.createSpy('f1spy').and.returnValue(4),
    jasmine.createSpy('f2spy').and.returnValue(5),
    jasmine.createSpy('f3spy').and.returnValue(6),
    ...
  ]
  let mockMap = spyOn((file1 as any).myMap, 'get').and.callFake((key) => {  // this fails
    var spy;
    switch(key) {
      case 'key1': spy = spies[0]; break;
      case 'key2': spy = spies[1]; break;
      case 'key3': spy = spies[2]; break;
      ...
    }
    return spy;
  }

  result = file1.doThing(...);

  expect(spies[0]).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(spies[1]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(7);
  expect(spies[2]).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, I get an error on the annotated line above: `Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for get()`. Upon further investigation (i.e. the step-by-step debugger), it turns out that the `file1` object I imported *only has `doThing()`*, and doesn't have any of its other private variables.

How do I successfully mock the key-value transformation here - which means, in this case, spying on attributes of a private variable, so I can get my spies in the right place? Either replacing `myMap` entirely or replacing `myMap.get()` would be an option, if either is possible.

Comment: I am not sure if this is good or not but I believe if you do `spyOn(((file1 as any).myMap as any), 'get')`, it should work and remove the `private` barrier.

Comment: @AliF50 Doesn't work, unfortunately. The `file1` in question is an entire module, not a class, so I don't think the non-exported attributes are even there on the object for me to get to via typecasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General idea: use [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire).

Using `rewire`, we will override your private functions with `spy` functions.

However, your `const myMap` needs to be modified. Because when you do `['key1', f1]` - it stores current implementation of `f1`, so we can't override it after `myMap` was initialized. One of the ways to overcome this - use `['key1', args => f1(args)]`. This way, it will not store `f1` function, only the wrapper to call it. You might achieve the same by using `apply()` or `call()`.

Example implementation:

`file1.ts`:

```
function f1(): number {
  // do far-reaching things
  return 1;
}

const myMap: Map<string, (x: number) => number> = new Map([
  ['key1', (...args: Parameters<typeof f1>) => f1(...args)],
]);

export function doThing(): number {
  const key = 'key1';
  const magicNumber = 7;
  const fileToExecute = myMap.get(key);
  return fileToExecute(magicNumber);
}
```

`file1.spec.ts`:

```
import * as rewire from 'rewire';

it('calls the correct fake method', () => {
  const spies = [jasmine.createSpy('f1spy').and.returnValue(4)];

  const myModule = rewire('./file1');

  myModule.__set__('f1', spies[0]);

  myModule.doThing();

  expect(spies[0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(7);
});
```

In order to use `rewire` with typescript, you might want to use babel, etc.

For proof of concept, I'm just going to compile it:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/tsc rewire-example/*
```

and run tests:

```sh
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine rewire-example/file1.spec.js
```

Which will run successfully:

```
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
```

UPDATE

Without modifications to `myMap`:

`file1.spec.ts`:

```
import * as rewire from 'rewire';

it('calls the correct fake method', () => {
  const spies = [
    jasmine.createSpy('f1spy').and.returnValue(4),
    jasmine.createSpy('f2spy').and.returnValue(5),
    // ...
  ];

  const myModule = rewire('./file1');

  const myMockedMap: Map<string, (x: number) => number> = new Map();

  (myModule.__get__('myMap') as typeof myMockedMap).forEach((value, key) =>
    myMockedMap.set(key, value)
  );

  myModule.__set__('myMap', myMockedMap);

  // ...
});
```

Comment: As a possible modification to this, would it be possible for keep it defined as it currently is, and use whatever is imported by `rewire` to do something like `myModule.__get__('myMap')`, then modify the resulting object?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I will appreciate if you mark this as accepted answer if it answers your question, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. *Jasmine*, as far as I know, doesn't use any compiler-kind magic, so it's impossible for *Jasmine* to get access to you private variables.
2. > From a client's point of view, `doThing()` is the only function it cares about. Thus, it's the only one exported by this file.

   but this doesn't mean that you should deprive your tests from the access to over staff. Instead you can create two files

   `file1.ts` - for a client

   ```js
   import { doThing } from "./file1_implementation"
   export doThing
   ```

   and `file1_implementation.ts` - for your tests

   ```js
   export function f1(...) ...
   export function f2(...) ...
   export function f3(...) ...
   export const myMap ...
   export function doThing(...) ...
   ```

   then in `file1.spec.ts` you can use `file1_implementation.ts` and you'll have access to everything you need

   ```js
   import * as file1 from '../src/file1_implementation'
   ...
   ```

Comment: Note that depending on your compiler / bundler settings even this can fail to work. E.g. this technique stopped working in Angular 9 due to some bundler settings change: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17207#issuecomment-599657518

Answer (score 2):

Can you just make file1 into a class? Then you can definitely access its private methods / attributes from jasmine.

so file1 becomes:

```
export class FileHelper {

  private f1 () : void {}
  private f2 () : void {}
  private f3 () : void {}

  private myMap: Map<whatever, whatever>;

  public doThing () : void {}

}
```

then in your spec:

```
let mapSpy: jasmine.Spy;
let myFileHelper: FileHelper;

beforeEach(() => {
  myFileHelper = new FileHelper();
  mapSpy = spyOn(<any>myFileHelper, 'myMap').and.callFake(() => {
    //whatever you were doing
  });
});


it('should do whatever', () => {

});
```